# Shared calendar with editing rights, Apple Calendar + Google Calendar App Smartphone

Tags: iphone, calendar, google-calendar

my friends and I are currently looking at setting up a shared calendar which we can all edit and add/delete events from the calendar apps on our smartphones. Some of us use Apple Calendar and some use Google Calendar. I, Google Calendar, have tried sharing a Google Calendar to their email addresses but the link in the email sends them to download Google Calendar.

I guess a rudementary solution to this problem would be that we all decide on one Calendar App, but some people have to then use two Calendar apps, one for the shared calendar and their original main.

Anyone got experience with this and can recommend a setup fitting to our case?

Best regards

UPDATE: To clarify, it's the "edit" functionality that is causing problems I believe. Subscribing to either a Google calendar with Apple Calendar or vice versa is pretty easy, but then just some can edit events.